# Is there any way to encapsulate a simple LINQ query in an extension method that can be used with LINQ to Entities query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, notsupportedexception

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but they are usually asking LINQ to Entities to support functions it doesn't or the solution offered is not what I'm looking for.

I have a SIMPLE query that I want to encapsulate in an extension method so it can be used everywhere:

```
public static Episode Latest(this ICollection<Episode> EpisodesSet)
{
    return EpisodesSet.OrderByDescending(e => e.AiredDate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This produces a NotSupportedException with the error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '[namespace/type/method here]' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

So, by "simple query" I mean that `OrderByDescending(expression).FirstOrDefault()` is supported/translatable by LINQ to Entities.  Also, I know that I COULD write a function that returns an Expression and do something like `episode = Episodes.Where(Latest())` but this doesn't seem very "discoverable" and is not the solution I'm looking for.

I would like to know if there is way to rewrite my extension method so that LINQ to Entities doesn't throw the NotSupportedException when I try to use the extension method like this:

```
var query = from show in context.Shows      
            select new {show.Title, show.Epsiodes.Latest()};
```

Comment: your choices are create some corresponding procedure (doing the same thing) on your database or try building your own Expression tree.

Comment: You can do this using **LinqKit**. You should check it out!

Comment: Latest returns an `Episode`; `where` requres a boolean value.

Comment: @Servy, I think I meant something like `episode = Episodes.FirstOrDefault(EpisodesDescending)`

Comment: @threadster I doubt it, because that code would work.  He wants to call the method from within an expression used by a query provider, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Servy, (I am he btw), that solution just doesn't cut it for me - I might as well just use the query expression from the extension method wherever I need to.

Comment: If you really want to use the method outside of the scope of a larger query it will work just fine.  It's only an issue if you're trying to use it inside of another query, and your only example of the latter is flawed, and won't even compile, let alone run.  You need to provide some examples of what you're actually trying to do that isn't working.

Comment: @Servy, I can make it work, just not the way I'd like. I'd like to encapsulate the extension method query expression in a way that can be used in any query anywhere. I updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is some what of a calculated property:

```
show.Epsiodes.Latest()
```

Basically you want to run code inside a Linq to Entities query. That's not posible.
Linq to Entities will never understand what `Latest()` means.

What you can do is, as you said, give an Expression and (probably) use LinqKit in order to reuse it everywhere you need it.

There are a couple of options to use calculated properties with Linq to Entities. Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611150/is-there-any-way-to-call-a-none-linq-method-inside-the-select-new-part-of-an-iqu/19614417#19614417).

What you probably want is the second option. This way you will be able to do something like this:

```
var query = from show in context.Shows      
            select new {show.Title, show.LatestEpsiode};
```

Provided that you define a calculated property in your `Show` class the way it is described [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider).